# javascript <body onload="do_something()">not work

Tags: javascript, html

I have an easy JavaScript Code and I do not know why it does not work. the code is :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function do_something() {
        alert(a);
        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var theImg = document.createElement("img");
        var a = 1；
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++, count++) {
            if (i == 5) continue;
            if (count == 3) {
                count = 0;
                a--；
            } else {
                a++;
            }
            if (i > 7) break;
        }
        alert(a);    
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="do_something()">
    
  </body>
</html>
```

but it does not display the value of "a", so maybe it is the problem of body onload?  Thanks.

Comment: This code can't display anything, it should show alert with current `a` value.

Comment: The value of a is undefined as you are assigning the value for 'a' later.

Comment: The thing is, after removing the first alert a, it still does not show the second alert a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function do_something() is not defined because of some illegal characters in your function after `var a=1` and `a--`, replace those with ';'
Also you need to initialize a before using it, otherwise it will given `undefined`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function do_something() {
        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var theImg = document.createElement("img");
        var a = 1;
        alert(a);
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++, count++) {
            if (i == 5) continue;
            if (count == 3) {
                count = 0;
                a--;
            } else {
                a++;
            }
            if (i > 7) break;
        }
        alert(a);    
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="do_something()">
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using 'a' before you define it. The variable declaration gets hoisted up, but 'a' isn't initially assigned a value.

Comment: after removing the first alert("a");  it still does not work

Comment: So it turns out there were a few issues with your code. Mainly, your code used some unusual punctuation, as Dij pointed out.  The issue I pointed out was also something to keep in mind, but it wasn't the biggest problem

Answer (score 0):

put the function directly after the div, tag or whatever:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function do_something() {
        alert(a);
        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var theImg = document.createElement("img");
        var a = 1；
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++, count++) {
            if (i == 5) continue;
            if (count == 3) {
                count = 0;
                a--；
            } else {
                a++;
            }
            if (i > 7) break;
        }
        alert(a);    
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          do_something();
      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it still does not work, error message is "Uncaught ReferenceError: do_something is not defined", which is "do_something();"

Answer (score 0):

here is the fact:

1) It is perfectly working locally.

2) In jsfiddle, you have to remove onload option from javascript.after that, it'll work fine. because it creates two call of onload funtion which gives error.

/-> please remove alert of 'a' before defining it.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to alert the value of `a` before it is declared. So you will get `undefined` error.

Check below snippet. It alerts the value of `a` in the second alert.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function do_something() {
        alert("a");
        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var theImg = document.createElement("img");
        var a = 1;
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++, count++) {
            if (i == 5) continue;
            if (count == 3) {
                count = 0;
                a--;
            } else {
                a++;
            }
            if (i > 7) break;
        }
        alert(a);    
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="do_something()">

  </body>
</html>
```